# how to delete multiple random keywords from a file using python

Tags: python, file

I have a file named hello.txt , which contains the following:

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
```

Now I as a user choose to remove two keywords from this file, namely four and two, in one single click.

Comment: Will keywords ever have spaces in them?

Answer (score 0):

Implementations may vary depending on file format, libraries used and such.

Let's assume we have a file like:

```
file = "1 one\n" \
       "2 two\n" \
       "3 three\n" \
       "4 four\n" \
       "5 five\n"
```

Our keywords to remove are as following:

```
keys_to_remove = ["two", "four"]
```

Now, a simple algorithm, we add a line to new file only if a keyword is not present in it:

```
new_file = str()

for line in file.split("\n"):
    do_append = True
    for key in keys_to_remove:
        if key in line:
            do_append = False

    if do_append:
        new_file += line
        new_file += '\n'

print(new_file)
```

And the output:

```
1 one
3 three
5 five
```

Comment: Note that I'm not sure if "removing content from file" in place is possible. I know many solutions to that problem though, you can either: `1` parse file and put results in new file and then replace the old one with a new one or `2` load whole file to memory and rewrite the old file with new content or `3` replace file content in place char-by-char with the same amount of bytes as it had before. That's why we are creating a `new_file` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your file into a list of lists, then looping through to remove any with the keyword.

```
file = open('hello.txt','r')
fileData = file.readlines()
newFileData = []
file.close()

removeThese = ['two','four']

for line in fileData:
    line = line.split(' ')
    if line[1] not in removeThese:
        newFileData += line

file = open('hello.txt','w')
for line in newFileData:
    file.write(' '.join(line))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

my basic query is :

i have a file "hello.txt"
its content are like this -->

1 sony
2 samsung
3 nokia
4 iphone
5 toshibha

now user will be asked which two mobile u want to check out

then user will give 3 and 5

So after accepting the user request the two mobiles should be deleted from the hello.txt.

same should work for if user selects 3 mobiles or any n items

Comment: It is better for you to incorporate your additional information into your original post so that everyone will see it. Putting it into the answer section (which it doesn't really belong to) is effectively hiding this information. Just a friendly suggestion/thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
new_file_data = []
file_data = [line.strip() for line in open("test.txt", "r")]
remove = ["five"]

for c in file_data:
        if c not in remove:
            new_file_data.append(c)

with open("test.txt","w") as file:
        for c in new_file_data:
            file.write("".join(c) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks to the solution ..this started working for me.